# Variable numeros might have not been initialized compilation error in java?

Tags: java

Hello commnunity I am begginer and I´m trying to fill the variable "numeros" creating a method called "Llenar" and It works, but When Im triying to call the method "EncuentraMayor" sending the variable "numeros" in the second case, I get the variable "numeros" might have not been inicialized. I think it was inicialized on the first method. Thanks for your help.

```
do{
    System.out.print(menu+"\nIngrese el numero de opcion");
    opcion=leer.nextInt();

    switch(opcion){

        case 1:
            numeros=Llenar();  
            for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++)         
                System.out.println(numeros[i]);
        break;

        case 2:
            int[]r;
            r=EncuentraMayor(numeros);
            System.out.print("El numero mayor ingresado es: "+r[0]+"."+"\nSu posicion es: "+r[1]);
        break;

        case 3:
            EncuentraMenor(numeros);
        break;

    }    
}while((opcion>0)&&(opcion<4));

public static int[] Llenar(){
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] x;
    int n=0;
    System.out.print("¿Cuantos numeros va a ingresar?");
    n=leer.nextInt();
    x= new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
       System.out.print("Ingrese numero "+i+1);
       x[i]=leer.nextInt();
    }    
    return x;
}
public static int[] EncuentraMayor(int[]x){
    int mayor=0,pos=0;
    int r[] = new int [2]; 
    mayor=x[0];
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(mayor<x[i]){
            mayor=x[i];
            pos=i;
        }
    }
    r[0]=mayor;
    r[1]=pos;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Debes que usar Stack Overflow en español: http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an array `numeros` and initialize it like this if not exist, but if it exist you need just initialize it:

```
  ...
  int[] numeros = new int[some lenght];

  System.out.print(menu+"\nIngrese el numero de opcion");
    opcion=leer.nextInt();
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`numeros` is only assigned in the first `case`. The variable is simply not in scope in the others, hence the error. You need to declare the variable before the switch statement, or inside each `case` separately.